# Licensing and commercial use

Tags: windows, licensing, gnu

I found a really cool piece of software under the AGPL license. I haven't heard of this before, so excuse the ignorance... But is it legal for me to simply bundle and use this product directly within my app (no modification) and resell for commercial use? Speaking of which, is there a simple table available that shows the implication of each open source license and whether or not it can be used by closed source, for-profit, $$$ type software?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear in your question how your program relates to this AGPL software. There are at least two possibilities:

1. If your software keeps the AGPL code as a clearly separated component that your code uses as an external program (e.g. in Java/GWT, Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params)), then your program does not need to be licenced as AGPL and you do not have to distribute the sources of your code, but you must make the sources of the AGPL software as easily available as your application (section 6d of AGPL v3).
2. If your software merges somehow with the AGPL software, even just creating a wrapper around it, in a way that the separation is not clear or they cannot "reasonably [be] considered independent and separate works in themselves", then your program can be considered a derivative work and therefore must be licenced as AGPL, and you must distribute the source code of both your program and of the original AGPL software.

I would like to stress that there is nothing wrong with charging for access / use of AGPL software. You only need to provide the source, nothing prevents you from charging a fee or earning money from advertising (like those websearch companies that run on modified linux kernels).

Comment: From where did you conclude #1? Please provide reference. 

Please see this answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/107931/72961

which says that even linking to (A)GPL is also not allowed from closed source/proprietary code.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License
Both versions of the AGPL were designed to close a perceived application service provider "loophole" (the "ASP loophole") in the ordinary GPL, whereby using but not distributing the software, the copyleft provisions are not triggered. Each version differs from the version of the GNU GPL on which it is based in having an additional provision addressing use of software over a computer network. The additional provision requires that the complete source code be made available to any network user of the AGPL-licensed work, typically a Web application.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. According to Wikipedia the AGPL license is just like the GPL license with added clauses for use over a network.

The long answer is yes, but you'd also have to publish your source. Some applications use this structure, for example the official XChat windows builds.

Comment: Ok, but in my case this is almost a third-party application... It's made accessible through my app, but really not used by my application in any other way (no code is compiled, modified or integration with my core product). So, am I still obliged to publish my source?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you're using something like system("AGPLapp") I think this might be a gray zone, but once again, I'm not sure.